# blank space in the top of the plot matplotlib django

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I've a question about matplotlib bars.
I've already made some bar charts but I don't know why, this one left a huge blank space in the top.

the code is similar to other graphics I've made and they don't have this problem.

If anyone has any idea, I appreciate the help.

```
x = matplotlib.numpy.arange(0, max(total))
ind = matplotlib.numpy.arange(len(age_list))

ax.barh(ind, total)

ax.set_yticks(ind) 
ax.set_yticklabels(age_list)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By "blank space in the top" do you mean that the y-limits are set too large?

By default, matplotlib will choose the x and y axis limits so that they're rounded to the closest "even" number (e.g. 1, 2, 12, 5, 50, -0.5 etc...).

If you want the axis limits to be set so that they're "tight" around the plot (i.e. the min and max of the data) use `ax.axis('tight')` (or equivalently, `plt.axis('tight')` which will use the current axis).

Another very useful method is `plt.margins(...)`/`ax.margins()`.  It will act similar to `axis('tight')`, but will leave a bit of padding around the limits.

As an example of your problem:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make some data...
age_list = range(10,31)
total = np.random.random(len(age_list))
ind = np.arange(len(age_list))

plt.barh(ind, total)

# Set the y-ticks centered on each bar
#  The default height (thickness) of each bar is 0.8
#  Therefore, adding 0.4 to the tick positions will 
#  center the ticks on the bars...
plt.yticks(ind + 0.4, age_list)

plt.show()
```

[image: Auto-rounded y-axis limits]

If I wanted the limits to be tighter, I could call `plt.axis('tight')` after the call to `plt.barh`, which would give:

[image: Tight axis limits]

However, you might not want things to be too tight, so you could use `plt.margins(0.02)` to add 2% padding in all directions.  You can then set the left-hand limit back to 0 with `plt.xlim(xmin=0)`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make some data...
age_list = range(10,31)
total = np.random.random(len(age_list))
ind = np.arange(len(age_list))

height = 0.8
plt.barh(ind, total, height=height)

plt.yticks(ind + height / 2.0, age_list)

plt.margins(0.05)
plt.xlim(xmin=0)

plt.show()
```

Which produces a bit nicer of a plot:

[image: Nicely padded margins]

Hopefully that points you in the right direction, at any rate!

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I had a graphic like the first one you draw, after making the changes I was able to see one similar with yours!
You explained very well and it make sense :)